# Is there a chart that shows Mhps mint speed over time?

Tags: difficulty, hashpower

My BitMinter client says that my approximate mint speed is 0.0078/per day on a MacBook Pro Retna.

I assume that this value decreases as the speed of the network increases, and therefore my contribution per block is less valuable.

- Is there any chart that illustrates how Hhps diminishes value over time?
- Would this chart correspond with the difficulty value/over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the total hash rate will correspond to the difficulty. After all, difficulty is adjusted based on how fast hashes are found.

[Here is a chart](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/) on sipa.be that shows hash rate on the left axis and difficulty on the right.

[Here is another](http://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate?timespan=all&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=0&address=) hash rate chart from blockchain.info.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of hashes per second your hardware performs is based solely on your hardware and software.

The current speed of the network is irrelevant to how much your contribution will earn.  The only thing that matters is the current difficulty.   An amount of hashing above or below that difficulty level will indicate the direction of the next difficulty adjustment, but for the next block, your mining returns depend on the difficulty and nothing else.

Here's a spreadsheet with the raw data:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmcTCtjBoRWUdHVRMHpqWUJValI1RlZiaEtCT1RrQmc

And here's the difficulty chart (blue):

[image]

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/oimg?key=0AmcTCtjBoRWUdHVRMHpqWUJValI1RlZiaEtCT1RrQmc&oid=10&zx=2bny6fbyhfqd

Comment: I suppose I need to ask "is there a chart that correlates Mhps to difficulty"

Comment: hash/s = difficulty*(2^32)/600seconds